# Why is this nuclear reaction $p\to n+e^++\nu$ forbidden for a free proton?

Tags: nuclear-physics, energy-conservation, mass-energy, proton-decay

Why is this nuclear reaction forbiden for a free proton?
$$p\to n+e^++\nu$$
Where $p$ is the proton, $n$ is a neutron, $e^+$ is a positron, and $\nu$ is a neutrino.

What i´ve been thinking is because of the relaivistic kinect energy:

$$m_pc^2=m_nc^2+m_{e^+}c^2+m_\nu c^2$$
$$(m_p=m_n+m_{e^+}+m_\nu)c^2$$
$$Q=(938 -940-0.511-0)c^2$$ 
$$=-2.511   Mev$$

Comment: Well the calculation you just performed shows that the reaction needs to take in 2.511MeV

Comment: yeah, energy conservation.  Not to worry, I always figure getting the sign right can be the hardest part.

Comment: Is someone going to post that as the answer? I feel satisfied by it.

Comment: This is actually close to being a good question, it's just that it seems like you've already answered it. So it's not clear what's left to ask. That's why it's been put on hold as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments to the question point out, already the calculation of energies gives the answer, conservation of energy, as the neutron is heavier than the proton.

There exist [proposed theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay#Theoretical_motivation) where the proton can decay:

p+      →       e+      +       π0

π0      →       2γ

This is not allowed within the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, which  model is a distillation of innumerable experimental facts.

As the universe we know exists, including us, it is evident that this reaction will have a very small probability. A number of [experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay#Experimental_evidence) have set a limit on proton decay, compatible with the great experiment of the existence of the observable universe.

Since any unification theory will have this possibility through new exchanged bosons, it will also have to fit the constraint that experimentally protons are stable.